# Arithmetic overflow in IIS when loading 8 gb to memory in application start

Tags: .net, iis, memory

I've got a web service that needs to return responses real time (under 100 milliseconds end to end) that needs to hit a 200 million record listing.  Due to this, our architect has decided to load the whole thing into memory on application start, it uses about 8 GB of memory.  On my local machine it runs no issues, but when I put it in IIS 8 on our test box I run into this error:

```
[OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.]
   ARS_WebService.Global_asax.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +197
```

My guess is the IIS Worker Process is just giving up, and/or doing a memory clean due to size used, but I've set the app pool to not reset due to memory.

EDIT:
Solved, nothing to do with the size of the IIS Worker, entirely due to system differences with converting between IntPtrs and Strings.

Comment: Can you check in Event Viewer if the application pool is recycling or not?

Comment: I don't see one for it, but I do see a Service Control Manager Device Association Service Stopped in the System Logs that matches the time stamp in the Application Logs

Comment: IIS should write an Event in case of application pool recycle. You can confirm this by setting a memory limit for your pool. If you don't see it, then it doesnt recycle or is unable to write the Event. Can you monitor memory usage or w3wp.exe during start up and see if there is a consistent limit?

Comment: I turned on logging for manual resets, and got one by doing a manual reset, I can now confirm that I am not getting a app pool reset along with this error.

Comment: So, did you get to monitor the w3wp.exe memory usage?